# How do i add .gitignore to all branches in repositories in Git?

Tags: git, github

I have more than 5 branches in my repository.
I want to add .gitignore file to each branch and push it to remote repository.

I tried running following commands one by one after cloning remote repository.

Commands i ran in sequence:

```
 for branch in $(git branch --all | grep '^\s*remotes' | egrep --invert-match '(:?HEAD|master)$'); do    git branch --track "${branch##*/}" "$branch"; done

for branch in $(git branch); do    git checkout $branch && touch .gitignore; done

for branch in $(git branch); do    git checkout $branch && git status; done

for branch in $(git branch); do    git checkout $branch && echo ".classpath" >> .gitignore && echo ".project" >> .gitignore && echo ".settings/" >> .gitignore && echo "log/" >> .gitignore && echo "target/" >> .gitignore ; done

for branch in $(git branch); do    git checkout $branch && git add .gitignore; done

for branch in $(git branch); do    git checkout $branch && git commit -m 'Adding gitignore'; done

for branch in $(git branch); do    git checkout $branch && git push -u origin $branch; done
```

Dont know but it doesnt perform as expected.

Please help.

Comment: Why do you run multiple loops? Combine all `for branch in $(git branch); do ... done` loops into one.

Comment: How many branches (more than 5) do you have in your repo? It surely takes less time to `git checkout`, `git add`, `git commit` on each of them than to try a lot of commands then to post this question and wait for an answer.

Comment: i tried combining still aint working .. thats why i moved on another approach of dividing them.. final result will be same

Comment: and it adds gitignore on first branch being checked out in for loop only... It doesnt add add in other branch being checked out :(

Comment: No mention of cherry picking anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

First, `git branch` is meant to be user-friendly, not programming-friendly.  Don't use it for programming: use the programming-friendly "plumbing" command, `git for-each-ref`.

Second, as [Leon said in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40676930/how-do-i-add-gitignore-to-all-branches-in-repositories-in-git#comment68583697_40676930), write your script—a one-off script is a good idea, it's much easier to write and use repeatedly, if needed, on new (fresh, clean) clones, until you get it right—with one loop that does everything necessary inside the loop.

Last, don't do the `git push` *here* at all.  Do it separately.  Git has a built in way to push "all branches".

Your first loop reads (with my formatting):

```
 for branch in $(git branch --all | grep '^\s*remotes' |
         egrep --invert-match '(:?HEAD|master)$'); do 
     git branch --track "${branch##*/}" "$branch"
 done
```

This looks like you want to take your existing *remote-tracking branches* (`origin/*` or whatever) and create new local branches from them, with the new local branches set to have the corresponding remote-tracking branch as their upstreams.  You exclude `master` here for some reason (I think I know the reason), and you also exclude the annoying symbolic HEAD ref that shows up as:

```
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
```

Your remaining loops do not exclude `master` (but also fail to handle the `*` that `git branch` prints, so they are going to produce some error messages at least).  Thus, it looks like you want to do this action on `master` too.  That means you are probably skipping it in the first loop just because it already exists, which is usually true<sup>1</sup> in a fresh clone.

So, let's write something that we expect to run on a fresh `git clone`, i.e., one that has no branches other than `master`.  (Though, see footnote 1 again.)  We'll try to fix other bugs along the way as well.

There is one minor issue: we will assume here that the name of the remote is `origin`, so that the remote-tracking branches have names starting with `refs/remotes/origin/`.  This makes it easier to loop over all the names and strip off the `origin/` prefix.  We'll start our script, then, with this:

```
for name in $(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/remotes/origin); do
```

This will iterate over all the shortened names: `origin/HEAD`, `origin/master`, and so on.

Next, we want to skip those that are in fact symbolic references like `HEAD`.  We could just skip the literal HEAD, which is a lot simpler.  The fancy way is to use `git symbolic-ref` to test it, but there is no point, the only actual one we'll see (for historical reasons) is HEAD, so let's just do this:

```
    [ "$name" = origin/HEAD ] && continue
```

Now what we need to do is create and check out a *local* branch that has the corresponding remote-tracking branch set as its upstream.  We can do this in one easy step using `git checkout`, which has that built-in.

This also lets us avoid special-casing `master`: `git clone` already ran `git checkout master`, which created `master` and set it up with `origin/master` as its upstream, but we will need to use `git checkout master` anyway.  This will check out the *existing* `master` that `git clone` created (when `git clone` ran `git checkout master`).  So our next step is to construct the correct branch name:

```
    branch=${name#origin/}
    git checkout $branch
```

We only want to strip `origin/`, not "everything up to the last slash", in case one of the remote-tracking branches is named `origin/feature/life` and another is named `origin/feature/zorg`, for instance.  We'll need local `feature/life` from which we can update `origin/feature/life`.

If the branch is `master`, it already exists, and this checks it out.  If the branch is anything else, it does not exist, but since this is a fresh clone, only one remote-tracking branch *does* exist—the one with `$name`—so we'll create the local branch and check it out, and it will have the remote-tracking branch set as its upstream.

Now we want to create a `.gitignore`, put a bunch of stuff in it, add it, and commit it.  One important question is whether a `.gitignore` already exists in the commit we just checked-out, and if so, what we want to do about it.  I can't answer that question for you.  Another is whether any of the files we are about to add *to* this `.gitignore` exist in the commit we just checked-out, and if so, what to do about *that*.  Again, *I* can't answer this.  I will note, however, that `touch .gitignore` followed by `git status` will only print something if `.gitignore` is newly created by `touch`.  It might be more sensible to test directly:

```
    if [ -f .gitignore ]; then
        ... do whatever should be done here ...
    else
        ... create it ...
    fi
```

If "whatever should be done" is "nothing special", we have it easier, as we can simply add to it using `>>`, which will create it if it does not exist, or add to if it does exist.

Rather than five separate `echo ... >> .gitignore`, we can use one `cat >> .gitignore` and a "here-document":

```
    cat << END >> .gitignore
.classpath
.project
.settings
log/
target/
END
```

Now we `git add` and `git commit` as usual, and that is the end of our loop:

```
    git add .gitignore
    git commit -m 'add gitignore'
done
```

Write all of this into a shell script file (`/tmp/doit.sh` or `/tmp/t.sh` are my favorite names for such scripts).  Add a `#! /bin/sh -e` line or `set -e` at the top and make the file executable—the `-e` ensures that the script will exit if any of the commands fails for any reason.  (Add `set -x` for debug as well.)  Add an explicit `git clone` line before the loop, so that it clones the repository, so that we are sure to have a fresh clone.  Remember to change directory into the clone as well.

The rest of this example puts the new repo into a directory named "newrepo".  It might be better to make a temporary directory with `mktemp -d`.

```
#! /bin/sh -e
# set -x  # for debug
[ -d newrepo ] && { echo "error: newrepo directory already exists"; exit 1; }
git clone scheme://example.com/path/to/repo.git newrepo
cd newrepo
for name in ... # see above for the rest
```

Now you can run `/tmp/doit.sh` and make sure everything worked.  If so, continue; if not, fix the script and start over.

Once everything does work, we're ready to `git push`:

```
$ cd newrepo
$ git push origin 'refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*'
```

This last step is a push with a *refspec*, and the refspec here says "for each of my branches, do a polite (non-forced) push to origin using the *same name* on origin".  Since we made sure to have *our* branches have the same names—such as `feature/life`—as those on `origin`, this is just what we want.

(Note: the above is all entirely untested.  Beware typos and the like.)

Comment: can you put whole of script in end entirely.. keep above part as it is ..

Comment: @virendrao: it's really not that hard to assemble, BUT you have to decide what to do in that one incomplete section (of testing for existing `.gitignore`) or whether to leave it out.

Comment: as of now no .gitignore exist in any branch.. we can remove that part ...

Comment: i had script as abvove in question but it fails as ./environment_details.sh: line 19: warning: here-document at line 10 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `END')
./environment_details.sh: line 20: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: @virendrao: that implies you probably did not de-indent the here document - the `END` word must be at the beginning of line, all by itself. The separate `echo`s will work fine though.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved as per @torek suggestion, you can following script as follows to add .gitignore file:

```
#! /bin/sh -e
# set -x  # for debug
[ -d mydir] && { echo "error: mydir directory already exists"; exit 1; }
git clone <git-repo-url> mydir
cd mydir
for name in $(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/remotes/origin); do
     [ "$name" = origin/HEAD ] && continue
     branch=${name#origin/}
     git checkout $branch
     echo ".classpath" >> .gitignore && echo ".project" >> .gitignore && echo ".settings/" >> .gitignore && echo "log/" >> .gitignore && echo "target/" >> .gitignore
     git add .gitignore
     git commit -m 'adding gitignore'
done
```

Once above is done, push code using following command:

```
git push origin 'refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*'
```